# React Fast Refresh doesn't work with Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

When I use [React Fast Refresh](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin) with Webpack 5, the whole page is refreshed instead of just the component that changed.

---

**EDIT** the issue was caused by Webpack configuration, a proper configuration to fix the problem is posted as an answer below.

Comment: Have you tried the example config for devServer? -> https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/blob/main/examples/webpack-dev-server/webpack.config.js

Comment: Thanks for the examples link  Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work cause the page kept reloading indefinitely. However, I've trimmed down the Webpack config based on the examples and bumped React version to 18 since that's what was used in the examples. Unfortunately, the same issue persists.

Comment: I think I figured out what's wrong with my configuration. I narrowed it down using the official examples that @Keith provided, I'll post an answer below later with what was the issue in my configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue after looking into the official examples (thanks to @Keith for pointing me towards them).

The main issue was my `index.html` included a link to the `bundle.js` that wasn't needed. My Webpack configuration also included extra unnecessary configurations like `devMiddleware` & `static` properties.

Here's my folder structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── babel.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   └── index.html
├── src
│   ├── Hello.jsx
│   └── index.jsx
└── webpack.config.js
```

I'm providing my `index.html`, `webpack.config.js`, and `bable.config.js` here for future references:

#### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");
const ReactRefreshPlugin = require("@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

module.exports = {
  mode: isDevelopment ? "development" : "production",

  devServer: {
    hot: true,

    client: {
      logging: "error",
      overlay: true,
    },
  },

  entry: ["./src/index.jsx"],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "./index.html",
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ].filter(Boolean),

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
};
```

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Webpack 5 And React Fast Refresh</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = (api) => {
  // This caches the Babel config
  api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);
  return {
    presets: [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      // Enable development transform of React with new automatic runtime
      [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        { development: !api.env("production"), runtime: "automatic" },
      ],
    ],
    // Applies the react-refresh Babel plugin on non-production modes only
    ...(!api.env("production") && { plugins: ["react-refresh/babel"] }),
  };
};
```